# Invariant measure of a continuous group action

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, group-actions

Denote by $\mathcal{M}(X)$ the set of Borel probability measures of a  space $X$. This set is equipped with weak$^*$ topology defined by the convergence $\mu_n\to \mu$ if and only if $\int \phi d\mu_n\to \int \phi d\mu$ for every continuous map with compact support $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ be a continuous action, $G$ be a finitely generated group and $X$ be a compact metric space.

A measure $\mu\in \mathcal{M}(X)$ is called an invariant measure under $\varphi$ if $\mu(\varphi(g, A)= \mu(A)$, for every $g\in G$ and every measurable set $A$.
 Let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{M}(X)$ be a closed, convex and $\varphi_*$-invariant (this means that if $\mu\in\mathcal{A}$ , then $\varphi_{g,*}(\mu)\in\mathcal{A}$, where $\varphi_{g,*}(\mu)(A)= \mu(\varphi(g, A)$).

I claim that $\mathcal{A}$ has an invariant measure of $\varphi$. Since $G$ is a finitely generated group, hence it is countable, let $G=\{g_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, take $\nu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_{g_i,*}(\mu)$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is comact, the sequence  $\nu_n$ has a limit measure $\mu$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is convex and $\nu_n\in\mathcal{A}$, it follows that $\mu\in\mathcal{A}$ and also an invariant measure of $\varphi$.

Please help me to know that this proof is true.

Thanks

Comment: Have you proved that $\mathcal{A}$ was sequentially compact ? Moreover it's not entirely clear that $\mu$ is actually invariant.

Comment: For a counterexample, the finitely generated group $\text{SL}_2 \mathbb Z$ acts naturally on $\mathbb R P^1$, and this action does not have an invariant Borel probability measure.

Comment: @Max  Thanks, $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed set of a compact set, hence it is compact. I do not know that my proof is true, please help me.

Comment: @LeeMosher,  Thanks, I would like to know if $X=\mathbb{R}P^1$ is a compact space or not.

Comment: Compact does not, in general, imply sequentially compact. Given Lee Mosher's comment, your proof cannot be correct, and the two problematic points are the ones I raised.

Comment: @Max, If  $\mathcal{A}$ is sequentially compact,  then my proof is true?

Comment: Well there is still the problem of proving that $\mu$ is invariant, which does not seem clear.

Comment: This strategy can be made to work if the group G is amenable.

Comment: @LeeMosher Where can I find a proof that the action of $\operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R} P^1$ has no invariant measures?

Comment: While that's an interesting question, starting up a discussion in the comments to this post is not the proper place for it on math.stackexchange.